# Listing more than 100 records in Route 53 using Ansible

Tags: ansible, amazon-route53, ansible-facts

I'm currently using the [route53_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/route53_facts_module.html) module on a project. I have 250 record sets in one hosted zone. I'm having difficulty with listing all record sets in that zone. The Route 53 API works by returning pages of **maximum 100 records** at a time. In order to retrieve the next page, you must pass the **NextRecordName** response value to the route53_facts module's **start_record_name:** field (pretty straightforward).

The issue I'm having specifically is getting Ansible to do this. Presumably one would do this using a loop, e.g. in pseudocode:

```
start
get 100 records
do until response does not contain NextRecordName:
    get 100 records (start_record_name=NextRecordName)
end
```

In Ansible, I have written the below task to do this:

```
- block:
  - name: List record sets in a given hosted zone
    route53_facts:
      query: record_sets
      hosted_zone_id: "/hostedzone/ZZZ1111112222"
      max_items: 100
      start_record_name: "{{ record_sets.NextRecordName | default(omit) }}"
    register: record_sets
    until: record_sets.NextRecordName is not defined
  when: "'{{ hosted_zone['Name'] }}' == 'test.example.com.'"
```

...however, this does not work as expected. Instead of continuously paging through responses until no more records are left, it repeatedly returns the first 100 records ("the first page").

As I can see from the Ansible debug output, **start_record_name:** is repeatedly **null**:

```
"attempts": 2,
"changed": false,
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "aws_access_key": null,
        "aws_secret_key": null,
        "change_id": null,
        "delegation_set_id": null,
        "dns_name": null,
        "ec2_url": null,
        "health_check_id": null,
        "health_check_method": "list",
        "hosted_zone_id": "/hostedzone/ZZZ1111112222",
        "hosted_zone_method": "list",
        "max_items": "100",
        "next_marker": null,
        "profile": null,
        "query": "record_sets",
        "region": null,
        "resource_id": null,
        "security_token": null,
        "start_record_name": null,
        "type": null,
        "validate_certs": true
    }
},
```

...my guess is that the **| default(omit)** filter is always being executed. In other words, **record_sets.NextRecordName** is never initialized at this point in the task.

I'm hoping somebody can assist me in getting Ansible to return all records from a zone in Route 53. I think I've gotten tangled up in Ansible's looping behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Caveat this with "as best I can tell:"*

To answer your question, it actually seems that `until:` and `register:` do not interact in the same way that `when:` and `register:` do. The best explanation I have is that `until:` behaves like a database transaction: it rolls back the `register:` assignment if the conditional is false, meaning that when the body of the `until:` task is tried again, it uses the same parameters as the first time. The only thing which keeps an `until:` block from being an infinite loop is the `retries:` value.

So, in your specific case, I think this will do the job:

```
- name: initial record_set
  route53_facts:
  # bootstrap so the upcoming "when:" will evaluate correctly
  register: record_facts
- set_fact:
    # capture the initial answer
    records0: '{{ record_facts.ResourceRecordSets }}'
- name: rest of them
  route53_facts:
    start_record_name: '{{ record_facts.NextRecordName }}'
  register: record_facts
  when: record_facts.NextRecordName | default("")
  with_sequence: count=10
- set_fact:
    all_records: >-
      {{ record0 + (record_facts.results | 
           selectattr("ResourceRecordSets", "defined") |
           map(attribute="ResourceRecordSets") | list) }}
```

The `with_sequence:` is a hack because `loop:` (for which `with_*` is syntatic sugar) needs a list of items over which to iterate, but given that the responses that come back without `NextRecordName` will cause the `when:` to fail, skipping them, makes the (in your case) 3 through 10 items resolve almost immediately.

Then you just need to pull out the actual response data from the now `list` of `route53_facts:` replies, and glue them to the initial one to get the complete list.

---

Having said all of that, I am now convinced that `route53_facts:` (and any other AWS module that pushes the burden of that iteration into the playbook) behavior is a **bug**. The module caller already has a `max_items:` available to them, but it's an implementation detail that that any value can't be larger than some random pagination cut-off.

Comment: Your question is evidently extremely relevant: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/49457#issuecomment-444887328 but based on their answer, I'm not certain it's going to be fixed anytime soon

Comment: A massive thank you for this, Matthew. I can confirm that this approach has worked for me. A caveat here is that the "with_sequence: count=10"  will only work up to (I think) 1,000 record sets (100 max_items * 10). Regardless, this has gotten me out of a very frustrating situation - thanks once again!

Comment: See [my answer to a similar question about zones](https://serverfault.com/a/1014888/14858) for possible updates to this answer.